# Is there is any way for sliderInput() or sliderTextInput() to have NA or NULL default value?

Tags: r, shiny, slider, shinywidgets

Is there any way for shiny input which looks like slider to have initial NULL or NA value? Both `sliderInput` and `sliderTextInput` don't allow for their default value to be null.

I'm well aware that `selectInput` allows for that (by defaulting to `character(0)`) but its visual flair isn't valid for application I have been working on.

Their values need to be read after `actionButton` input, where some checks will be made to make sure all inputs were adjusted by the user.

I have some fundamentals of javascript, but need some direction on how to create a workaround.

Example minimal app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

UI <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput(
    "test_1",
    "Testing sliderInput",
    min = 1,
    max = 5,
    value = 3 # don't allow leaving empty, NA or NULL
  ),
  
  sliderTextInput(
    "test2",
    "Testing sliderTextInput",
    choices = c("1 - Least",
                "2 - Less",
                "3 - Middle",
                "4 - More",
                "5 - Most"),
    selected = NULL # allows NULL, but takes the first of 'choices' either way
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(UI, server)
```